# Standardizing $\latex$ use on the site to make searching for formulas easier

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is it possible to publish/link to/include a guide or a reference to a preferred guide to writing LaTeX on the site so that (if possible) searching by formula would be easier?

That's pretty much it...

Comment: There are various pertinent comments on [What notation and symbols are commonly used here?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/740/520). My take is that it will be very hard to get people to agree because different sub-fields use different standards.

Comment: @dmckee, That's not _exactly_ it... I'll edit first thing tomorrow...